# Should my objects hold objects or object IDs?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, oop

For example should I be doing this

```
class MyObject {
    private Long subObjectId; //such as this
    private List<Long> subObjectIds; //or this
    //bunch of other fields omitted
}
```

or

```
class MyObject {
    private SubObject mySubObject; //such as this
    private List<SubObject> mySubObjectList; //or this
    //bunch of other fields omitted
}
```

Which one is considered the typical / better approach? If I want to populate something like MyObject from a database, I don't know if my objects should be holding onto IDs or actually populate the objects themselves.

Is it considered bad practice to use the second method but keep the objects null until I *need* to populate them (a sort of lazy population approach).

The advantage of the first method is that it's quick and easy to populate, but then if I ever wanted to get access to the actual object the ID points to, then I have to query the database and populate some separate `SubObject` that is decoupled from `MyObject`.

I hope my question is clear enough. Thank you.

Comment: I'd prefer method 2, you remove the database fiddling from the client and provide a simpler abstraction. I've never heard of lazy population being a bad practice, but if you're not sure, why not both? Make `MyObject` an `interface` and provide a one-shot populate everything implementation, and a lazy populated one.

Comment: This will depend to some extent on the tools you have available. Android is more limited, but on a desktop/server JVM you'd absolutely use JPA to handle the mapping for you transparently.

Comment: @JornVernee I don't understand how that interface approach solves the issue? Can you provide an example of what you mean? (in my case MyObject has a bunch of other fields so it has more than just references to other objects; it may have its own fields which are pulled straight from the db)

Comment: @chrylis I think that's only true if the mappings / objects are really simple

Comment: You could always have SubObject extend Object, this way each SubObject has an Id, and if you query the DB and get all SubObjects in an array, you can just use .id() to grab every Id as you cycle through them.

Comment: Each SubObject in my case would have its own id (pulled straight from the database, the SubObject table that holds all the fields for SubObject). But each SubObject would also have a foreign key pointing to the id field of MyObject, so when I populate MyObject I'd also be querying for any SubObject with MyObjectId = MyObject.getId() -- is this the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using some ORM like hibernate, then references are the way to go.

If you are not using an ORM, then ids are the way to go.  If you start using references without an ORM, you are going to start running into situations where you need a reference but all you are receiving from the database is an id, and the only way to overcome these situations is by writing your own ORM.  Don't re-invent that wheel.

Comment: "you are going to start running into situations where you need a reference but all you are receiving from the database is an id" what? If my CRUD methods are populating the sub-objects then why would they only get IDs?

Comment: If you try to do that, then every time you encounter a certain sub-object id you will be creating a new sub-object to hold it, but if you have already encountered that id then you do not want to create a new sub-object, you want to find the previously created sub-object with that id and reuse it.  Which is (among many other things) what ORMs do for you.

Comment: And you might ask, "why would I want to reuse the existing sub-object?" well, because if you modify it, you will only be modifying that one instance of it.  All other instances of the sub-object with the same id will remain unchanged. Chaos and destruction.

Comment: I still do not understand what you are saying. Every time I "encounter" a certain sub-object id? Let me back up: What is wrong with doing this: I know MyObject's id, call it someId. So I query all fields from MyObjectTable with id = someId. I also query SubObjectTable via foreign id key MyObjectId = someId. Once I have all these results, I can instantiate all the SubObject objects and attach them into MyObject.

Comment: Well, if you are planning to read the entire database into memory at once, that's a different story.  I read your OP again and it kind of follows from what you wrote, but I did not realize it at first.  The problems arise if you do not have the luxury of loading everything into memory at once, so you keep querying the database afterwards, and then you need to know what ids you see for the first time, and what ids you have seen before.  So, if you are sure you will always enjoy this luxury, ignore my answer, it is inapplicable to your situation.

Comment: I'm not reading an entire database into memory at once -- just the stuff corresponding to the designated id (in the example I just gave). There may be tons of other data in the database with other IDs but I am referring to a scenario where I am only populating for a specific id.

Comment: I also still do not understand the answer even as it's given. If I have the object reference, can't I just do object.getId() to get the id?

Comment: I did not say that once you have a reference it will be hard to obtain an id.  I spoke of having an id and wanting a reference.  In that case you need to search through your objects to first see if you have already created an instance for that id.  And when you cannot rely on having everything in memory, you need to maintain a cache of objects you have loaded so far, but then you have to be discarding objects from that cache as you start running out of memory, and it gets messier and messier.

Comment: I think that gets to the "decoupling" problem I was trying to describe in the original post? Like you have to maintain a separate cache to hold the objects if you choose to populate them (assuming you are going with IDs only). Are you saying that ORMs provide this "separate cache" in some form? But if all I have are IDs isn't the ORM basically just doing "ok here's the ID, now I'll query the db, and store the object reference in my own cache that the user can access"?

Comment: If I am not using an ORM then you say I should use IDs, but then how do I maintain all the object references? Would I have to sort of juggle all the objects separately?

Comment: If all objects of a certain table fit in memory, you are fine with those.  Otherwise, yes, you are going to have a lot of juggling to do.  Which ORMs do for you.

Comment: So for example if I have a Location and a LocationCategory, I would make it so Location's constructor accepts things like an ID, name, and a LocationCategory object? (as opposed to accepting a LocationCategoryID). And in the query for populating the Location object I would also be querying / creating the LocationCategory object?

Comment: How does an ORM handle the juggling for you exactly? Let's assume I go IDs only. How would I then get the references that correspond? SubObject subObjectThatIWant = ORM.getSubObjectById(someId); ? And in its backend it maintains a map of IDs to object references or something?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works, in the rare event that you have an id in your hands and want the unique object corresponding to that id.  But the ORM mostly spares you from even having to do that and gives you references to your objects.  It provides the illusion of having everything in memory at all times, despite the database being so large that it cannot all reside in memory.

Comment: But let's say I don't have an ORM. Then in my function where I populate Location, I would also query LocationCategory and populate the locationCategory object and then do something like Location.setLocationCategory(locationCategory); correct? But then once this function ends and I return Location, does the location category go out of scope and make the reference to locationCategory from inside Location become null?

Comment: Yes you can do that, and no, in java if you hold a reference to an object somewhere, anywhere, then the object will not disappear.

Comment: Very helpful conversation for me -- thank you very much

Comment: Sure, glad to be of help.  Going to sleep now.  Good night!